# Getting error response 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: docker, nvidia

I managed to get docker and ubuntu running on my PC. My goal is to get cuOpt running on my PC. Im attempting to follow instructions from https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/teams/cuopt/containers/cuopt .
When I try running $ sudo docker login nvcr.io I get this response

Error response from daemon: Get "https://nvcr.io/v2/": received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

How do I go about this?
Let me know if you need additional information, thanks!

Could the service be literally temporarily unavailable?
[image]
This has been loading for eternity now :o